# React-Redux Configuration with Typescript Error on Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to learn how to setup Typescript with React-Redux so that in the future i do everything with TS, just for the sake of learning.
I only want to have an action that will generate a bi dimensional array of numbers.
So this is what im doing:

My Action

```
import { GENERATE_PINS, AppActions } from '../types/actions';
import { generateAllPins } from '../utils/generatePins';
import { AppState } from '../configStore';
import { PinArr } from '../types/pinType';
import { Dispatch } from 'react';
// TypeScript infers that this function is returning SendMessageAction

export const getPin = (pins: PinArr): AppActions => ({
  type: GENERATE_PINS,
  pins
});

export const startGeneratePin = () => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>, getState: () => AppState) => {
    const pins = generateAllPins();
    return dispatch(
      getPin({
        pins
      })
    );
  };
};
```

My reducer

```
import { PinArr } from '../types/pinType';
import { GENERATE_PINS, PinActionTypes } from '../types/actions';

const initialState: PinArr = {
  pins: []
};

export function pinReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: PinActionTypes
): PinArr {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GENERATE_PINS:
      return {
        pins: [...state.pins, ...action.pin]
      };
  }
}
```

My types

```
import { PinArr } from './pinType';

export const GENERATE_PINS = 'GENERATE_PINS';

interface GeneratePin {
  type: typeof GENERATE_PINS;
  pin: PinArr;
}

export type PinActionTypes = GeneratePin;

export type AppActions = PinActionTypes;
```

And my data interface

```
export interface PinArr {
  pins: Array<Array<number>>;
}
```

My pins should be a result like [ [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [2,6,4,2]...]
So thats why im doing Array>

Right now i have two erros:
ON pin action

```
Type '{ type: "GENERATE_PINS"; pins: PinArr; }' is not assignable to type 'GeneratePin'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'pins' does not exist in type 'GeneratePin'. Did you mean to write 'pin'?
```

On reducer

```
Type 'PinArr' is not an array type.
```

Anyone can help me ? I feel like once i understand and solve this interface types (and this is why im using TS, to evolve as a developer overall) i will feel confortable using TS with React.
Please?

Comment: `GeneratePin` refers to `pin` but your object is providing `pins`. `pin` seems to be a property of `PinArr`

Comment: ok that was my b.
i still get Type 'PinArr' is not an array type.

Comment: Because `PinArr` should be an object which has `pins` as a property. If you want `PinArr` to be an array type you should do `type PinArr = Array<Array<number>>;`

Answer (score 0):

You've confused yourself because of your naming convention (names matter)! What you have declared as `PinsArray` is *actually* the slice of state that `PinReducer` handles. I think it will make much more sense in your code if you name things like so:

```js
type PinsArray = number[][]

interface PinState {
    pins: PinsArray
}
```